# Do I need TVS with Optocoupler relay

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, tvs

I am connecting digital output from a camera to a light source using a relay (see below).

[image]

The relay uses SONGLE SRD-5VDC-SL-C Optocoupler:

[RELAY DATASHEET](http://www.datasheet-pdf.com/PDF/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet-Songle-720556)

The camera manual says *"Uses an open-drain NFET transistor with the source connected to GND in camera. If used
with an external relay, a diode must be connected in parallel with the load for protection
against voltage transients. Max loading is 100 mA."*

It seems to me there would be little possibility of transient voltage.  I am seeking advise if the TVS or Flywheel diode is really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the relay you've chosen is not an opto coupler. If its a mechanical relay it will have a coil with an inductance and it can't change it's current instantly, the flyback diode provides a path for the current when the coil is switched off. Otherwise, a voltage spike will occur causing arcing on switch contacts .
TVS diodes are used between the supply/signal and Ground for transients. What you should be looking out for are flyback diodes. perhaps schottky diodes would be ideal for this application

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a diode or TVS in this case. The component you have is an optically isolated relay -- there is already a diode built in. The opto isolation just allows the controller (camera) to be optically isolated from the load (relay & relay outputs).